# Click on previous button in browser make an ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a problem (no wayyy !?)..
Like I said in my browser, when I click on the previous button, it makes an AJAX request..
So it could be a little bit disturbing for the users of my website.
So why it does this ?
and how to solve it ?

Here the code concerned in my controller.
I'm using Laravel 4.1.

```
        if (Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json($viewContent);
        }

        return View::make($viewName, $viewContent);
```

Please, Thanks.

EDIT: I confirm that 'Previous' button mean the browsers back button.

Comment: Can you confirm that 'Previous' button means either the browsers back button or an on-page button.

Comment: I edit to confirm browsers back button

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I discovered that when my chrome console is opened it doesn't make an AJAX request when I click on the previous button of my browser.. so it returns the View I wish.

Tell me that someone has been in the same situation..

Comment: were you able to solve it? I'm having the same issue